# How do I retrieve a related object using a Lookup field in Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a trigger for insert on Opportunity:

```
trigger OpportunityInsertTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {
    System.debug('Triggered on insert of opportunity. Updating blockchain...');
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        List<DNBCompany__c> retrievedCompany = [SELECT Id, Name, Duns__c FROM DNBCompany__c WHERE Id = :opp.DNBCompany__c];
        DNBCompany__c company = retrievedCompany.get(0);
        String duns = (String) company.get('Duns__c');            
    }
}
```

I have a custom object called DNBCompany that is linked via a Lookup relation (DNBCompany__c) in Opportunity.

How can I retrieve the DNBCompany associated with opp?

[EDITED to reflect answer below]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
{       
    DNBCompany__c retrievedCompany = [SELECT Id, Name FROM DNBCompany__c WHERE Id = :opp.DNBCompany__c];
}
```

Since the lookup field will be the `Id` of the company you want to retrieve, you can use an inline SOQL query to get the associated object back.

Keep in mind, you'll have to reference any additional fields you wish to process on in your SOQL query.

Comment: Is there not a more direct way to dereference the lookup field? Ie. opp.get('DNBCompany__c')?

Comment: This gives me a null:      DNBCompany__c company = (DNBCompany__c) opp.get('DNBCompany__c');

Comment: Tried the SOQL query above, and it's complaining about the type 'DNBCompany':

        DNBCompany retrievedCompany = [SELECT Id, Name, Duns__c FROM DNBCompany__c WHERE Id = :opp.DNBCompany__c];

'Invalid type: DNBCompany'

Comment: Definitely have a custom object "DNBCompany" with API name "DNBCompany__c"

Comment: Yeah, since I don't have your custom object, I figured it'd be helpful to provide an example. The API level name does need to be referenced as the retrieved object type, so I've updated to reflect that.